# bitmap interpolation c#

Tags: c#

Grid size : 160*160
No of row* columns = 16*16

I have created a bitmap for this. Each cell of the grid is filled with different colors. I need to perform color interpolation.

Comment: *"I need to perform color interpolation."* - That's fine... So what is your question?! :)

Comment: @ghetto: there must be a good question in there somewhere, 2 upvotes to prove it.

Comment: how to perform this using spline interpolation

Comment: we still have no clue. You want _what_ (1) interpolated between _what_ (2) and _what_ (3) ?

Comment: -1: This question should go away. Three years old, by the comments, no one understands what it is asking. I certainly can't. Annoying to encounter it in a search.

Answer (score 12):

I guess you want to do the following: Take a 16x16 pixel image and interpolate it to a 160x160 pixel image. Here are three sample outputs (you only said you want to use spline interpolation, but not which one):

1. Nearest neighbour
2. Bilinear (Applying [linear spline interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation#Linear_spline_interpolation) in both x and y direction)
3. Bicubic (Applying [cubic spline interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation#Cubic_spline_interpolation) in both x and y direction)

[original img http://img695.imageshack.us/img695/8200/nearest.png](http://img695.imageshack.us/img695/8200/nearest.png)
[linear interpolation img http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/3815/linear.png](http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/3815/linear.png)
[cubic interpolation img http://img709.imageshack.us/img709/1985/cubic.png](http://img709.imageshack.us/img709/1985/cubic.png)

The .net Framework provides those and a few more methods (see [MSDN, InterpolationMode Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.interpolationmode.aspx)).

This code will perform an image scaling. (I wrote an extension method, but you can leave away the `this` keyword and use it as a normal function):

```
public static Image EnlargeImage(this Image original, int scale)
{
    Bitmap newimg = new Bitmap(original.Width * scale, original.Height * scale);

    using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(newimg))
    {
        // Here you set your interpolation mode
        g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.Bicubic;

        // Scale the image, by drawing it on the larger bitmap
        g.DrawImage(original, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, newimg.Size));
    }

    return newimg;
}
```

You would use it like this:

```
Bitmap my16x16img = new Bitmap(16, 16);
Bitmap the160x160img = (Bitmap)my16x16img.EnlargeImage(10);
```

Comment: the bit map width is 160*160*4 and width and height of each pixel  is 16*16 and 4 is the pixelformat ARGB, Initally the each pixel set to black with alpha zero. Fill some of the cells with different color.  Now I wanted to perform the intepolation so that i will get a smooth image using cubic spline interpolation. Please let me know how to do this.

Comment: Do you mean you have squares of 16*16 pixels? One pixel can obviously not be 16x16 ***something*** large. Is the other thing not exactly what I described in my answer?

Comment: sorry the size of the pixel is 10*10. The bitmap size should not be reduce . Please check this link http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/ColorShading.aspx ,this is what required by using cubic spline interpolation

Comment: Could you perhaps just update your question and ask in understandable plain english what you want to archieve with all this? The article (link you posted) describes again something completely different. And why dont you just download the sourcecode to that article from codeproject.com and take a look at that?

Comment: Hi, can you please fix the dead links?