# Re sampling Tiff Image

Tags: c#, image, tiff, resampling

I need to re sample a Tiff image based on Navigation line(Seismic survey data).for Ex: the Tiff image with width=9857 and height=1187 and I need to resize(downsize) to Width=2160 and height=1187. I have tried with default C# encoders and compression algorithm and I know this is a reducing the size of 70% from the original image size. It lost the resolution of the image during downsize. is there any way to avoid it??

```
    private static Bitmap LZWCompression(Image source, int width, int height)
    {
        Bitmap Destbitmap = new Bitmap(source, width, height);

        Destbitmap.SetResolution(300, 300);

        ImageCodecInfo myImageCodecInfo;
        myImageCodecInfo = GetEncoderInfo("image/tiff");

        System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder myEncoder;
        myEncoder = System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality;
        EncoderParameters myEncoderParameters;
        myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
        EncoderParameter myEncoderParameter;
        myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 100000L);
        myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;
        Destbitmap.Save(@"E:\Resized_LZW.tiff", myImageCodecInfo, myEncoderParameters);
        return Destbitmap;
    }


    private static ImageCodecInfo GetEncoderInfo(String mimeType)
    {
        int j;
        ImageCodecInfo[] encoders;
        encoders = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
        for (j = 0; j < encoders.Length; ++j)
        {
            if (encoders[j].MimeType == mimeType)
                return encoders[j];
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: so what is the question?

Comment: How to avoid resolution loss to the image during re sampling...

Comment: you cant fit 1000lb of stuff in a 1lb bag..

Comment: You're reducing the width to about 1/4, so it's clear that you lose a lot of detail. There's no way out of this, you just can try to use a different interpolation algorithm.

Comment: @SBS what other interpolation algorithm?, this is not normal images, this is seismic data

Comment: @Jey It doesn't matter where the image originates from. You've got a Bitmap instance and want to shrink it, and there are various algorithms to compensate the loss of detail, called interpolation. The .NET Graphics object has a InterpolationMode property, offering the following algorithms: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.interpolationmode(v=vs.110).aspx See this SO question for more information about how to use the Graphics class for interpolation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2666351/bitmap-interpolation-c-sharp